# Simple script to start store pid of a daemon

Tags: c, linux, sh, daemon, pid

I've managed to make a daemon using the following code. My question is I want to create a script to start this daemon and store the daemons PID in `/var/run/mydaemon.pid`.  Moreover, a second script to stop the daemon by accessing the stored `mydaemon.pid` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

static void daemonize(void)
{
    pid_t pid, sid;

    /* already a daemon */
    if ( getppid() == 1 ) return;

    /* Fork off the parent process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* If we got a good PID, then we can exit the parent process. */
    if (pid > 0) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    /* At this point we are executing as the child process */

    /* Change the file mode mask */
    umask(0);

    /* Create a new SID for the child process */
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Change the current working directory.  This prevents the current
       directory from being locked; hence not being able to remove it. */
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Redirect standard files to /dev/null */
    freopen( "/dev/null", "r", stdin);
    freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stdout);
    freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stderr);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    daemonize();

    /* Now we are a daemon -- do the work for which we were paid */


    return 0;
}
```

I've look around and can't seem to find example code to help me. The closest thing I've got is something you see below. But it's not working.

```
#!/bin/sh


set -e

# Must be a valid filename
NAME=mydaemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid


DAEMON=/home/me/mydaemon/mydaemon/a.out


export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON 
        echo "."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: "$1" {start}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: "*its not working.*" is the more or less worth trouble report one can give.

Comment: Let the daemon call `getpid()` and have it print the result to `/var/run/mydeamon.pid`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3957242/694576 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662327/694576

Comment: Isn't `start-stop-daemon` specific to Debian?

Comment: Note that since you include `<stdlib.h>`, you should not define `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` — they're defined by the header.

Answer (score 1):

With the daemonizing code as written, you cannot determine the PID of the daemonized process you just started because that information isn't made available.  The parent process information would be available if you ran the program in the background (`$!` would report the PID if you use `./mydaemon &`), but that process just exited, leaving another process to run.

You need the help of the daemonizing code; the parent code should report the PID of the child process before exiting.

```
/* If we got a good PID, report child PID and exit the parent process. */
if (pid > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)pid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Now you can use:

```
NAME=mydaemon
# PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
# DAEMON=/home/me/mydaemon/mydaemon/a.out

pidfile="/var/run/mydaemon.pid"
pid=$($NAME)
if [ -n "$pid" ]
then
    echo "$pid" > "$pidfile"
else
    echo "$0: failed to launch daemonized process '$NAME'" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This relies on the code (in the daemon) not writing to standard output unless it is successful in forking.  It can write to standard error if it needs to report any errors.

Comment: Hi Jonathan Leffler thanks! when i run the script now i get /.startrevd.sh: failed to launch daemonized process ' ' is there something i missed?

Comment: I don't know — probably.  Or I missed something.  Suppose you run `mydaemon` from the command line; do you get a process number reported?  If so, assuming the number reported was 12345, can you see the process with `ps -fp 12345`? Can you send a signal to it — `kill 12345`?  If those cause problems, then you probably didn't modify your daemon correctly.  You may need to add the output from `sh -x startrevd.sh` to your question — note the word _add_ (leave most of the information unchanged).

Comment: yes for example 12345 does show up when i run the `./daemon` but when i type ps `-fp 12345` its empty...

Comment: Are you testing with `sleep(30);` or something similar as the 'work' done by the daemonized process?

Comment: Thanks now i can see and kill it after setting up with `sleep()` in the main. i dont really understand what you mean with adding `sh -x startrevd.sh` do you mean in the script? i tried that and ran the script and it just started to spam startrevd.sh repeatedly.

Comment: Now that the daemon daemonizes and runs for a while, you can start debugging the script.  I'm not clear about the name of the shell script you wrote based on my answer, but whatever that script is, that's the one to run prefixed with `sh -x`.  This runs the basic shell in a debugging mode that shows the commands it is executing as it executes them.  Now we need to see that the value returned by `mydaemon` is captured in variable `pid`, for example. Maybe your `/bin/sh` is different from the shell you normally use. Do you have a shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or similar) line?  If so, use that shell.

Comment: This is what im getting. What is supposed be in the NAME?                                                                                     + pidfile=/tmp/revd.pid
+ 
+ pid=
+ [ -n  ]
+ echo startrevd.sh: failed to launch daemonized process ''
startrevd.sh: failed to launch daemonized process ''
+ exit 1

Comment: I believe I said "You may need to add the output from sh -x startrevd.sh to your question — note the word add (leave most of the information unchanged)." once before.  I meant it.  You can't post debug output in comments sanely.  The question, though, will be "why is `pid=` line empty, and why isn't there a command echoed.  It could be that you didn't keep the `NAME=mydaemon` assignment from the original shell script that you quoted.  The `pid=$($NAME)` notation runs the command specified in the the variable `$NAME` and captures the output.

Comment: Oh sorry i accidentally removed `NAME=mydaemon` .. although now that i've restored it.. i get "mydaemon not found"

Comment: So, you need to ensure either that the daemon is in a directory on your PATH or you need to specify the full pathname to where the daemon is stored so that you can run it with an explicit pathname.

Answer (score -2):

You could return child pid on parent C program exiting return call
and read value from $? variable on calling script.

./myDeamon

childPid=$?

Comment: The `$?` returned status can only store values up to 255; PIDs cover a far bigger range.